# setting and getting ages based on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I asked a similar question but couldn't find the right solution. I have used a code to dynamically generate input fields that includes a date field followed by age.

I am trying jQuery's datepicker class to pick the dates and each age field calculates based on these select dates.

The problem is I don't know how to set the value of age input field. Tried and searched lots of posts and it may be a simple fix but since I'm not too familiar with jQuery methods, I got no luck to get it.

Please see excerpt from my codes:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function() {

    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var   dob = new Date(value),
         today = new Date(), 
        age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970; 
        $('.age').find('input').val(age);
       },
       
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",yearRange: "1900:+10",showOn:'focus'}).focus();
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Title: 
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname[]" value="" size="30" />  
Date: 
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dates[]" value="" size="10" /> 
Age: <input type="text" class="form-control age" id="age" name="age[]" value="" size="10" />   
<a href="#" 
class="remove">Remove</a></p>
```

I've tried text(), html(), val() with many other ways around but nothing works. The issue from above is setting a value to id in 'dob' input. I'd rather want it to appear in VALUE of 'age' input field. Hope I explained my issue properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in your question you are adding multiple input (date) fields dynamically followed by age. So using simple class **$(".age")** or id **$('#age')** selector will not work for you.

If you use $(".age").val(age) it will change value for all input with class age and if you use $("#age").val(age) it will update value only for first matching input with id age.

So, You need to use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) with [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$(ui.input).closest("p").find('.age').val(age);
```

OR

Use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector like this

```
$(ui.input).siblings(".age").val(age);
```

I hope it will help you.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function() {
  //don't add datepicker again if already exist
  if (!$(this).hasClass("hasDatepicker")) {
    $(this).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var dob = new Date(value),
          today = new Date(),
          age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
        $(ui.input).closest("p").find('.age').val(age);
        //$(ui.input).siblings(".age").val(age);
      },
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      yearRange: "1900:+10",
      showOn: 'focus'
    }).focus();
  }
});

$(document).on('click', "#add", function() {
  $(".wrapper").append('<p class="user-row">Title: ' +
    '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname[]" value="" size="30" />' +
    'Date: <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dates[]" value="" size="10" />' +
    'Age: <input type="text" class="form-control age" name="age[]" value="" size="10" />' +
    '<a href="#" class="remove"> Remove</a> </p>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("p").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="user-row">Title:
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname[]" value="" size="30" /> Date:
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dates[]" value="" size="10" /> Age: <input type="text" class="form-control age" name="age[]" value="" size="10" />
    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
  </p>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">ADD</button>
```

Comment: I've tried 'closest()' before which did not work but as soon as I combined with find() it worked like a charm! You save my days and I appreciate it so much. I'd better go through jQuery as soon as this project is done as I'm mainly focused on php.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `find('input')` in your code

```
$('.age').find('input').val(age);
```

into

```
$('.age').val(age);
```

Because with `$('.age')` you've already found the input, no need to use `find` to find it again. Document for find is [here](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> **Description**: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: As I've done it before and R.K.Saini mentioned this code only changes the id of 'dob' and its value gives not even age in number.

Answer (score 0):

1. change date format to `"mm/dd/yy"`
2. it should be `$('#age').val(age);`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function() {

        $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(value, ui) {
                var dob = new Date(value),
                    today = new Date(), 
                    age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
                 $('#age').val(age);
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            yearRange: "1900:+10",
            showOn:'focus'
        }).focus();
    });
</script>
```

Goodluck on coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need tp remove `.find(input)` because `$('.age')` should do the job. Also, you need to include jquery-ui for datepicker. The following should do the trick.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function() {

    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var   dob = new Date(value),
         today = new Date(), 
        age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970; 
        $('.age').find('input').val(age);
       },
       
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",yearRange: "1900:+10",showOn:'focus'}).focus();
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Title: 
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname[]" value="" size="30" />  
Date: 
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dates[]" value="" size="10" /> 
Age: <input type="text" class="form-control age" id="age" name="age[]" value="" size="10" />   
<a href="#" 
class="remove">Remove</a></p>
```